# Filter widget_pages_args not working in Pages Widget

Tags: filters, widgets

I try to use a filter to remove some pages from Widget Pages but it seems not to be working. What I am doing wrong?

```
  add_filter( 'widget_pages_args', 'custom_list_pages_filter', 10, 1 );

  function custom_list_pages_filter($args) {
     error_log(); 
      $remove = array(2); // or could be array(1,2,3,4)
      $args['exclude'] = implode( ',', $remove );
      return $args;
  }
```

Comment: Are you using the legacy pages _Widget_, or are you using the Block?

Comment: Its says Page List. How can I tell the difference, please? It's WP 6.0.2 with a Twenty Twenty theme child.

Comment: Finally I understand this is a block!, So the filter does not apply. Files are in /wp-includes/blocks/page-list/ and in the file block.json I found the title and description. The code is in file /wp-includes/blocks/page-list.php and there is no filter there:  $all_pages = get_pages(
  array(
   'sort_column' => 'menu_order,post_title',
   'order'       => 'asc',
  )
 );

Answer (score 0):

Now, that I have noticed Page List is a block widget. I think I have two solutions: a) Revert to classic widgets with the Classic Widgets Plugin and use the filter b) Create a new block and filter pages it my way. This one I think is much harder. Thanks to @jacob-peattie for the insight.